# get_children() Archive Template

Tags: wp-query, loop, templates, archives, get-children

This is my first attempt at coding & I have come unstuck with the wp_query loop integration.

I just want to build a template for a page that will check for children and list their respective Thumbnail and Title as links (see below example)

[image: example listing Archive template]

I have added the below code into `functions.php` (hope this is best practice)

```php
$childPages = get_children( array(
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'orderby' => array(
    'menu_order' => 'ASC',
    'title' => 'ASC'
  )
));
```

I am really having trouble grasping the loop on my `childTemplate.php`! I have respectively placed the following code in this template:

```php
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Child Archive
*
* @package WordPress

*/


  // Custom query.
  $query = new WP_Query( $childPages);
   

    if (sizeof($childPages))
        <div class="row">
          foreach ($childPages as $page)
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-4">
          <a href="get_page_link($page)"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail_url($page)" alt="$page->post_title"     class="img-fluid mb-2"></a>
              <h2 class="text-center"><a href="get_page_link($page)">$page->post_title</a></h2>
            </div>
          endforeach
    endif


  // Restore original post data.
  wp_reset_postdata();
   
?>
```

Would be awesome if somebody could review my coding attempt, and steer me in the right direction to grasping the wp_query + Loop part of the solution. I have been reading up on it but still struggling.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) (and other relevant pages/articles in the theme dev handbook) and the [`WP_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)? There are many examples there, including the correct syntax for `new WP_Query` - in your code, you're passing an array of post objects and that is wrong - you should instead pass an array of *arguments*, just like the ones you passed to `get_children()`.

Comment: Thx Sally CJ, I will refer those :-)